# How can I save the output of an API call to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am calling a REST API from lambda function in AWS . I receive the response in the terminal. How can I store these API responses in DynamoDB. I am sorry if this may seem naive to some. I am a beginner and self learner.

Comment: Wondering why not use the AWS SDK for DynamoDB in the language you are using to write the Lambda function. For example, if you are using Node JS, then you can use the AWS SDK for JavaScript in your Lamda function logic to invoke DynamoDB operations.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
If I understood correctly, I can add invoking DynamoDB directly in my lambda function using the AWS SDK for DynamoDB and store the incoming responses to DynamoDB?

Comment: [Step 3: Create, Read, Update, and Delete an Item with Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html). Depending on your API call which you are making to the REST API, you still have to parse the response and store in DyanmoDB what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example for a Python based Lambda function:

```
# Import AWS (Python version) SDK
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Construct the client to the DynamoDB service
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    table_name = 'my-awesome-table'
    # Table instance
    table = db.Table(table_name)
    
    # Example data to query an entry from the table
    primary_column_name = 'email'
    primary_key = 'john@gmail.com'

    # We get an object for the retrieved table entry
    table_entry = get_table_item(table, primary_column_name, primary_key)

    # Example data to put into the table
    new_entry = {
        'email': 'jack@outlook.com',
        'name': 'Jack Ma',
        'age': 56
    }
    put_table_item(table, new_entry)

# Function to retrieve an entry from the DynamoDB table
def get_table_item(table, primary_column_name, primary_key):
    response = table.get_item(
            Key={
                primary_column_name: primary_key
            }
        )
    
    return response['Item']

# Function to put an entry into the DynamoDB table
def put_table_item(table, item):
    response = table.put_item(
            Item=item
        )
    
    # If there were errors, throw an exception
    if (response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200):
        raise Exception('Failed to update table!')
```